# explanations of the code here, order of output in cout statement in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

 char c = 'a';
 int numb;

 for (int i = 1; i <= 25 ; i++){

    cout << c <<   "," << c++ << endl;

 }

}
```

Why is it that when I print the output above, the following will get printed:

```
b,a

c,b

d,c
```

But I was expecting:

```
a,b

b,c

c,d
```

Comment: It's up to the compiler to determine which order to do this in. [cout << order of call to functions it prints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/cout-order-of-call-to-functions-it-prints) has a detailed answer that should satisfy the question.

Comment: You probably meant `++c`. As-is, on a C++17 compiler the output will be `a,a`, `b,b` etc. Explore the [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) reference.

Comment: A bit of a guess here.  So ++ has higher operator precedence than <<.  So I'm guessing the ++ is done first.  So then the first << gets "b" because c has been incremented already.  However, the << c++ gets a, because it is a post-increment operation.  I am not a C++ compiler guy, but I'm pretty sure it is an operator precedence thing as I described.

Comment: @FrankMerrow the `<<` in this case is a function call so this becomes less order of operations and more a matter of when the parameters to those functions are acquired, and the rules on that have been changed a couple times in the last few Standard revisions. See the link in Ron's comment for the gory details.

Comment: This has [nothing to do with operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58976592/4386278), @Frank.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not compiling to the C++17 Standard revision or more recent you have encountered [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The older C++ Standards do not specify the sequencing of

```
cout << c <<   "," << c++ << endl;
```

so there are no guarantees on when that `c++` will occur. The only thing you can count on is the `c++` term will be the initial value because `++` increments after the value is collected.

```
a,a
```

or

```
b,a
```

are valid outputs.

As of C++17 the Standard guarantees that all side effects will be resolved before proceeding to the next `<<`. `<< c` will be resolved, not that there is much to resolve, before `<< ","` starts. `<< c++` comes even later in the chain. This means  you should always see

```
a,a 
b,b
c,c
```

See the notes on Undefined Behaviour at the bottom of [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Comment: hello, could you explain what you mean by "c++ is guaranteed to sequence after << c" ? could you provide an example of what that means? thank you

Comment: @john_w Your question is a near-perfect example, so I've tried to update the answer to better describe why the sequencing is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it has to do with the order of operations here. The stream operator (`<<`) operates from right to left. Meaning that in the first run, `c++` evaluates to "a", but causes `c` to be iterated up to "b".

Comment: This is actually a nasty case. In older compiler standards (before C++17) there are no firm guarantees on when that `c++` will occur.